# Promise inside the multiple promises in angular 6?

Tags: angular, promise, angular6, primeng

**Actual Problem**: Pagination is not showing in `p-table`.

**Solution**: We have to store all the data at once then Pagination will display. For this I am trying this method

Actually I am upgrading the p-Datatable to p-table in ngPrime. In p-datatable is loading with pagination,
but when I upgrading the Datatable to table pagination is not showing.

I looked on it. If I make the settimeout pageination is showing, but we can't use the settimeout(becuase I don't the no process and responsoe time).

So I have tried with promises, but still I can't able to make the each single promises.

My scenario is First I am making the one response using the response I am making the multiple responses and storing the data
into array. Finally I am using that array in p-table template. Below is my code

```
allArr = [];
allTemp = [];

ngOnInit():void{
    this.getVal.then((x)=>{
        this.allArr = x;
    })
}

getVal = new Promise( (resolve,reject)=>{    
    let resource = "path/name";
    this.log.getList(resource).subscribe(
    rst=>{
        for(var key in rst){
            this.getInfo(key.name, key.value);
        }
        //here I don't know where I have to resolve the promise

        //setTimeout(() => {
        //    resolve(this.serviceTemp);
        //},2000);

    })
}


getInfo(name, value): void{
    this.log.getDetail(name)
    .subscribe(
        (log: any) => {
            this.allTemp.push(log.detail);
        });
}
```

My template code

```
<p-table [columns]="tableHeader" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [value]="allArr" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedService" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,25]" 
[responsive]="true" sortField="serviceName" sortOrder="1" sortMode="multiple">
```

Comment: can you just call resolve(this.serviceTemp); after the for loop?

Comment: No. It is not working. I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Actually I want to make the promise all, for the inner subscribe not for the first calling function

```
allArr = [];
allTemp = [];

ngOnInit():void{
  getVal();
}
allPromise = [];

getVal(){    
    let resource = "path/name";
    this.log.getList(resource).subscribe(
    rst=>{
        for(var key in rst){
            allPromise.push(this.getInfo(key.name, key.value));
        }
        Promise.all(this.allPromise).then(()=>{
            this.allArr = this.allTemp;
        });
    })
}


getInfo(name, value): void{
    let _this = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        _this.log.getDetail(name)
        .subscribe(
            (log: any) => {
                this.allTemp.push(log.detail);
            });
    })
}
```